# Connection issues when router in bridge mode is between modem-router and user device

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, dhcp, arp

I decided to extend my home network's wireless coverage by utilizing a spare router. Both routers are modem-routers and have been provided by different internet providers the previous years. So, their WAN port is an RJ-11 one and they are of different brands with different characteristics.

Since they come with an RJ-11 port as WAN, I dropped the wan-lan connectivity option. The procedure followed is this:

### The procedure

1. The one modem-router is connected to the telephone RJ-11 socket. This is the master.
2. Master configured with the following settings:

   - LAN IP: 192.168.1.1
   - Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
   - DHCP start IP address: 192.168.1.2
   - DHCP end IP address: 192.168.1.253
   - Wireless channel is set to automatic
   - SSID is set to "master-wifi"
3. The other modem-router is my slave and configured like this:

   - DHCP server was disabled in order to operate in bridge mode
   - Firewall was disabled
   - LAN IP was set to 192.168.1.254, which is the only one in 192.168.1.1/24 domain that is not given to a devide by DHCP server of master.
   - Wireless channel is set to 6
   - SSID is set to "slave-wifi"
4. Master and slave were connected LAN-LAN with ethernet cable
5. Both routers were rebooted and then all devices were connected to "slave-wifi" with no issues.

*Diagram*
`{internet} ---- {modem-router} ---ether--- {modem-router in bridge mode} ---wifi--- {user device}`

### The problem

Having connected to "slave-wifi", when I choose to connect to "master-wifi" due to better signal depending on the house's spot I am at that time, I have issues returning back to "slave-wifi" at a later point of time.

In particular it seems that I am never getting an IP, apart from the temporary one given by my system, no matter how many time passes. When I set manually a static IP, let's say 192.168.1.20, with subnet 255.255.255.0 and gateway 192.168.1.1, I can successfully communicate with slave router, but not with master one.

Wireshark on my device, which transited twice from the one hot-spot to the other, shows me that ARP requests with content "Who has 192.168.1.1? Tell 192.168.1.20" are continuously broadcast, whithout getting back a unicast ARP reply.

However in master router's management page, the ARP table seems updated with the MAC address information for the 192.168.1.20 host. So, master seems to get the information needed from 192.168.1.20 hot, but the latter doesn't take the equivalent one.

The problem is resolved only after rebooting of master router only. The slave's one rebooting doesn't resolve the problem, and it seems it isn't necessary at all.

So, in the end I would like someone to make me understand what could be prossibly wrong, because it doesn't make sense to me.

### The end user devices

Keep in mind that the problem is the same for all my devices performed a double transistion of wireless hot spots: from "slave-wifi" to "master-wifi" and back again. My devices are the following:

- Macbook Pro of late 2017 with OS Catalina
- Lenovo ThinkPad T480 with Windows 10
- Smartphone Huawei P20 Pro

Thus the issue doesn't seem to be device oriented.

Comment: Is the problem also resolved by rebooting the computer? Does the router have settings for ARP Cache?

Comment: No, the problem is not resolved by rebooting the computer, and there is no settings for ARP cache in either router. You can only view the ARP table in master router, while the slave does not even provide this option. What I forgot to mention is that by giving "arp -i en0 -l -a" (en0 is my wireless interface) in terminal of Macbook Pro, I get the current ARP entries for my system. During the problem there is no MAC address for 192.168.1.1 in the output, but just an "incomplete" informative message, where normally the MAC address would be shown.

Comment: Does it work better with same SSID?

Comment: No it doesn't. In particular, I set both SSIDs as "master-wifi". My smartphone was initially connected to WiFi of master router. But when WiFi's signal of slave's router became stronger and transition was triggered, it never succeeded to actually connect, while ARP requests were constantly exchanged as already described.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. On a related note, my MacBook connected to the slave router through LAN never experienced any problems. It can seamlessly switch between the slave WiFi, master wifi and the slave LAN. Not sure if the problem is specific to Android. Hope you will update the question if you were able to rectify it.